# nodejs filter for mongodb data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using node and MongoDB for my project, here I need to set the filter on node script so that the data comes out from my MongoDB is filtered. But I do not understood how to use filter functionality on my script. It will be a filtered method, or I can use find method, or use loop
to filter the data in my MongoDB using node js script.

I am not exactly getting the idea.

What I want to do?

1) I had sent a set off a question from my MongoDB to the frontend.

2) Questions Data is coming from the front end and saved via using node js API. I have to save questionId, a score.

3) Next time when I have to send the data I NEED FILTER HERE so that data I have sent previously not sent again.

Id will generate automatically in MongoDB. So I have not mention id here.

This is my question schema

```
title: {type: String, required:true},
options: {type: Array, required:true},
result: {type: Array, required:true},
```

here i am storing my questionid, score values coming from frontend.

This is my question id, score save schema

```
child: {
    quiz: {
        questionId:{type:String},
        score:{type:Number},
        time:{type:String}
    }
}
```

This is my node js API filter. I am trying this but I am not sure this is right or wrong. Please help me to fix this proble.m

```
this.childfilter = function(req, res, next) {        
    async.waterfall ([
        function(callback) {
            try {
                var query = { 'child.quiz.score': 1 };
                var projection = '';
                childinfo.find(query,function(err,data) {
                    if(err) return next(err);
                    res.send(data);
                    callback(null, data)
                });
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            }
        },
        function(callback, data) {
            try {
                var childq = new childquestion();
                var query = { 'data.child.quiz.questionId' : childq._id }; 
                var projection = 'id title options result';
                childquestion.find(query,projection)
                    .skip()
                    .exec(function(err,data){
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    res.send(data);
                });                        
            }        
            catch(err) {
                console.log('Error While Saving the result ' +err);
                return next(err); 
            }
        } 
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Do you want `quiz.questionId` to be unique value?

Comment: you suggest it is compulsory or not

Comment: No I mean, `quiz.questionId` can not be repeated in another record.

Comment: Can you give a sample data structure? I am not sure how you are planning to store it, specially the `child` part. `quiz` you have shown as object, so there will be multiple `child` with `quiz` field inside it?

Comment: sorry I have no data structure for this, but I have a single child and it quiz field inside it

Comment: can I do this with a for loop